Non-relativistic Quantum Mechanical Scattering Theory Textbook Recommendations
I am looking for textbooks that cover non-relativistic quantum mechanical scattering theory. An ideal text would not "brush mathematical details under the rug" and would also make contact between the theory being described and actual experimental design. A set of textbooks rather than a single text which satisfy the above two requirements would also be appreciated.

The book on scattering theory by Taylor, and the book on the same topic by Newton.
